# The difference between an UML meta-model and an UML profil?

Tags: model, uml, profile, metamodel

Please explain the difference between a UML profile and a UML meta-model.

Answer (score 0):

UML meta-model is predefined in the UML specifications.  For example,  a primitive type, a class, an operations are elements of the meta-model.

A profile is a package that that allows to extend or specialize ethe meta-model.  For example: you could define in a profile:

- a new stereotype `«persistent  entity»`  that extends the class element of the meta-model.
- a new type `Double` could be added to the types, if the standard primitive types such as `Real` are not precise enough.

Comment: One small addition: `Real` is not a meta-type. It is rather defined as an instance of the meta-class `PrimitiveType` in a standard _library_. Therefore, it might be misleading to show `Double` next to «persistent entity». They are on different modeling levels.